# How to get details through association in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I have four models in rails; location, path, feature and feature type. But I'm struggling to set up some of the associations.

- A feature has one location and one feature type
- A path has 2 locations, from and to

From Feature I can run

- Feature.first.location - and get the location it applies to
- Feature.featuretype - and get the feature type that it is related to.

From Featuretype I can run

- Featuretype.first.features - and it returns all of the features that use this feature type.

From Location I can run

- Location.first.features - and it returns all of the features that are linked to this location.

I would like to be able to run

- Location.first.paths - and return all paths that use that location.
- Path.first.locations - and return both locations in the path.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :features
end

class Path < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :LocationFrom, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'from'
    belongs_to :LocationTo, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'to'
end

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :featuretype
    belongs_to :location
end

class Featuretype < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :feature 
end
```

This is my db schema if it helps

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160813164514) do

  create_table "features", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "featuretype_id"
    t.string   "featurename"
    t.string   "featuredescription"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "location_id"
  end

  create_table "featuretypes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "latitude"
    t.string   "longitude"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "paths", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "from"
    t.integer  "to"
    t.integer  "distance"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean  "directed"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Featuretype < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :feature # Should be :features, (notice the pluralization)
end
```

Rename the relation. Naming convention is snake case.

```
class Path < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location_from, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'from'
  belongs_to :location_to, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'to'
end
```

In `Location` create a method which queries `Path` for the wanted rows

```
def paths
  Path.where "from = :id OR to = :id", id: id
end
```

In `Path` create a method which returns the both locations as an array

```
def locations
  [location_from, location_to]
end
```

Comment: Are these methods to be added to the models or controllers?

Comment: I could not get these methods to work. I had to use `[Location.find(from),Location.find(to)]` and `[Path.where(from: id),Path.where(to: id)]` instead which both produce the result I'm after.

Comment: What error did you get when running the `paths` method?

Comment: I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "from": syntax error: SELECT "paths".* FROM "paths" WHERE (from = 4 OR to = 4)`

Comment: @Conor try to remove the whitespaces around `=`

`"from=:id OR to=:id", id: id`

Comment: `"from=:id OR to=:id", id: id` still produces the same error.

Comment: @Conor which rails version are you on?

Comment: I'm running Rails 4.2.6